# Comparing 2 timestamps to check 30 days always fails

Tags: javascript

I have the following 2 timestamps and I am trying to check if `testTimestamp` is older than 30 days...

```js
// Monday, 9 March 2020 08:59:29
var testTimestamp = 1583744369;

// 30 Days Previous To Current Timestamp
var thirtyDaysTimestamp = new Date().getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

if(parseInt(testTimestamp) > parseInt(thirtyDaysTimestamp)) {
    console.log('Timestamp is more than 30 days');
} else {
    console.log('Timestamp is not more than 30 days');
}
```

This looks like it should work but whatever timestamp I test it always tells me is is `not` more than 30 days.

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Javascript timestamps are in milliseconds. So Monday, 9 March 2020 08:59:29 is 1583744369000. And "older" means "less".

Also you might need to take care of timezone if you hardcode the value.

```js
// Monday, 9 March 2020 08:59:29
var testTimestamp = 1583744369000;

// 30 Days Previous To Current Timestamp
var thirtyDaysTimestamp = new Date().getTime() - (30 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000);

if(testTimestamp < thirtyDaysTimestamp) {
    console.log('Timestamp is more than 30 days');
} else {
    console.log('Timestamp is not more than 30 days');
}
```